# filter products by product option value (Mysql query)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
id | product_id | option    |  option value
-------------------------------------------
1  |    3       |    size   |   m
2  |    3       |    color  |   red
3  |    3       |    brand  |   apple
4  |    5       |    color  |   red
5  |    5       |    weight |   16m
6  |    6       |    size   |   m
```

i am get two product `product_id [3,5]`

now i am filter this products with option value

my filter `option_value [m]`
here, `m` `option_value` presence in `product_id 3` but not presence in `product_id 5`, so only show `product_id 3`

Again, filter `option_value [red]`
here, `red` `option_value` presence in `product_id 3 and 5`, so all my gets products are show `product_id 3,5`

Finaly, filter `option_value [m,red]`
here, `m` and `red` `option_value` presence in `product_id 3` but `m` `option_value` presence in `product_id 5` and `red`
`option_value` not presence in `product_id 5`, so show product_id blank
That means, i get that products who's option value are same as filter `option_value`

how to write this mysql query?

Comment: I have question the option_value is array or single value

Comment: option_value  is array

Comment: I've posted a answer with SQL:queries why to get the first two filter options... i don't fully understand the third filter conditions can you elaborate a output example? "That means, i get that products who's option value are same as filter option_value" what does this mean and output?? "so show product_id blank" with blank you mean display NULL?

Comment: sorry one question, i filter my product which option_value is [m,red] ... where two option values is match existing filter products, I'll take that product rows

Comment: yes third condition result is null, because two option value are not exist on filter products

Answer (score 0):

> my filter option_value [m] here, m option_value presence in product_id
>   3 but not presence in product_id 5, so only show product_id 3

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  Table1.product_id
FROM 
  Table1
WHERE
 table1.product_id IN(3, 5)
GROUP BY 
  Table1.product_id
HAVING
 SUM(Table1.option_value = 'm') = 1
```

Result

```
| product_id |
|------------|
|          3 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17e393/8

> Again, filter option_value [red] here, red option_value presence in
>   product_id 3 and 5, so all my gets products are show product_id 3,5

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  Table1.product_id
FROM 
  Table1
WHERE
 table1.product_id IN(3, 5)
GROUP BY 
  Table1.product_id
HAVING
 SUM(Table1.option_value = 'red') = 1
```

**Result**

```
| product_id |
|------------|
|          3 |
|          5 |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17e393/9

Comment: yes third condition result is null, because two option value are not exist on filter products